# Android implementing ObservableScrollView library

Tags: android, android-listview, android-library, android-toolbar

I am trying to implement ObservableScrollView library in my project.
I have my code organized as follows:

- The Toolbar is the main activity
- The ObservableListView (ListView is the type) is within a fragment

I followed the documentation, I searched examples, but I can not implement it properly.

Tengo varios problemas, el primero es que al estar en un fragment, no puedo implementar esta línea:

```
listView.setScrollViewCallbacks(this)
```

the getActivity instead of "this" is not valid, I have also tried:

```
Activity parentActivity = getActivity();
listEntriesWeb.setScrollViewCallbacks((ObservableScrollViewCallbacks) parentActivity);
```

This really is validated in the code but I get a crash when running.

Another problem is that I have obtained the method to show or hide the toolbar of the documentation:

```
public void onUpOrCancelMotionEvent(ScrollState scrollState) {

        if (scrollState == ScrollState.UP) {
            if (((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().isShowing()) {
                ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
            }
        } else if (scrollState == ScrollState.DOWN) {
            if (!((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().isShowing()) {
                ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().show();
            }
        }
    }
```

But do not know how you run this method.

```
 onUpOrCancelMotionEvent(ScrollState.DOWN); or  onUpOrCancelMotionEvent(ScrollState.UP);
```

... But from where I use it? the usual setOnScrollListener not work with me ObservableListView.

What am I doing wrong?
I appreciate the help to implement this library

Thank you very much and greetings.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first question the Fragment has to implement ObservableScrollViewCallbacks.

```
public class ListViewFragment implements ObservableScrollViewCallbacks {
    ...
    listView.setScrollViewCallbacks(this)
    ...
}
```

then passing this to setScrollViewCallbacks will work without having to pass an activity (or you can pass the activity but then the activity has to implement said Callback).

As soon as you implement the Callback the onUpOrCancelMotionEvent should be called as well I think.

Answer (score 0):

For Resolving this issue You have to implement ObesevableScrollViewCallbacks interface to your activity class

```
public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ObservableScrollViewCallbacks {
    .
    .
    oScrollView = (ObservableScrollView) findViewById(R.id.oScrollView );
    oScrollView .setScrollViewCallbacks(this);
    .
    .
}
```